# How can I label a node that is the initial vertex in a cycle from graph data

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to implement an algorithm such that in a collection of unique and ordered graph edges, I can find a cyclic node.

E.g. for **`a ->b, b->c, c->a`**, then `'a'` is a cyclic node and thus I want to annotate it in this edge with `'a@'` and simillar for others.

As example data I use this:

```
a = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('f', 'e')]
```

Then this would become:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a@'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a@'), ('f', 'e')]
```

How can I achieve this in python?

This is what I tried:

```html
collection = {}
data, result = [], []
for i, j in a:
    if i in collection.keys():
        collection[i].append(j)
    else:
        collection[i] = [j]
    if j in collection.keys():
        for item in range(len(collection[i])):
            if collection[i][item] == j:
                nr += 1
                collection[i][item] = j + '@'

print(collection)
```

It seems to work for cycles but it also takes into account strong connected components that are not cycles.. So I am looking for something similar like networkx simple cycles (no subcycles), also I need data returned in this way like above.

Comment: Why are you annotating the second and the fourth `a` but not the first and the third?

Comment: Because in those edges, that specific 'a' will also represent the initial 'a' who is the source of the cycles. So for a->b, b->c, c->d, d->a I will only want to annotate the last 'a .I am doing this to convert graph data to tree data.

Comment: I would say that you should annotate the third then, the second `a` is closing the cycle. Anyway you may want to look into [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) for graph analysis.

Comment: Why is `a` the only node annotated in your example? What makes it the "initial" vertex of the cycle?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You seem to have applied *some* naive algorithm to derive the example output already. What do specifically do you need help with to implement it?

Comment: I edited now for more information @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Do you define a cyclic node as the first node of the cycle that you encounter in the edge sequence?

Comment: Yes, and when it is met again I annotate it with '@

Comment: What are `data, result = [], []` in your example? what is `nr += 1`? What exact type of result do you expect - `list` or `dict`? Is output ordered?

Comment: It looks like no one understands you. Could you include your other examples and their expected output to your question? I mean example from your previous duplicate and example under @Ivan Popov answer. Could you explain exactly which node should be marked as a a cyclic node and why?

Answer (score 3):

This solution builds all possible paths that it encounters in the edge list, since we don't really know where a cycle starts. It also prunes the path list that it creates to prevent some memory bloat if your graph is large. It is ugly but works based on your needs.

```
a = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('f', 'e')]

annotated = []
paths = []
for edge in a:
    new_paths = []
    paths.append(''.join(edge))
    annotated.append(edge)
    cycle = ''
    for path in paths[:]:
        if path.endswith(edge[0]):
            if path.startswith(edge[1]):
                annotated[-1] = (annotated[-1][0], annotated[-1][1]+'@')
                cycle = path + edge[1]
            else:
                new_paths.append(path + edge[1])
        else:
            new_paths.append(path)
    paths = [x for x in new_paths if x not in cycle]
    print(paths)
print(f'Result: {annotated}')

"""
Out:

['ab']
['abc', 'bc']
['abcd', 'bcd', 'cd']
[]
['ae']
[]
['fe']
Result: [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a@'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a@'), ('f', 'e')]
"""
```

Comment: For [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'z'), ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'c'),
     ('z', 'a'), ('z', 'y'), ('z', 'b')] it will fail though.  ('z', '@a'), and ('z', '@b') do not exist

Comment: True. However, in that example (z, c@) should also exist, since we have the sequence `(c, d), (d, z), (z, c)`. Your definition of start and end of a cycle is arbitrary, and those edges are not 'sorted' in a logical manner. What would be the output for the sequence `(c, d), (z, c), (d, z)`?

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: for `a ->b, b->c, c->a`, then `'a'` is a cyclic node and thus I want to annotate it in this edge with `'a@'` and simillar for others.

Mark the last node with `'@'` if a valid chain of nodes, e.g. `a ->b, b->c, c->a`, is found.

```
def mark_cycle_end(nodes, initial, marker='@'):
    chained = None, None
    cycle_start = None

    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        if cycle_start is not None \
            and chained[0] == chained[1]:
            chained = nodes[i - 1][1], node[0]

        if node[0] == initial:
            cycle_start = i
            chained = None, None

        elif node[1] == initial:
            start, end, end_ = cycle_start, i, i + 1

            if chained == (None, None):
                print('missing start node, end is: {}'
                      .format(nodes[end:end_]))
            elif not chained[0] == chained[1]:
                print('missing link {} in {}'
                      .format(chained, nodes[start:end_]))
            else:  # is chained
                print('mark:{}'
                      .format((start, end, nodes[start:end_])))
                nodes[end] = (nodes[end][0], nodes[end][1] + marker)

            cycle_start = None
            chained = None, None
```

> **Usage**:

```
nodes1 = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('f', 'e')]
nodes2 =  [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'z'), ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'c'), ('z', 'a'), ('z', 'y'), ('z', 'b')]

MATCH1 = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a@'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a@'), ('f', 'e')]

for nodes, match in ((nodes1, MATCH1), (nodes2, nodes2)):

    mark_cycle_end(nodes, initial=nodes[0][0])

    if nodes == match:
        match = 'MATCH:'
    else:
        match = '!!!!!:'

    print('{}{}'.format(match, nodes))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> mark:(0, 3, [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a')])
> mark:(4, 5, [('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a')])
> MATCH:[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a@'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a@'), ('f', 'e')]
> missing link ('z', 'b') in [('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a')]
> missing start node, end is: [('z', 'a')]
> MATCH:[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'z'), ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'c'), ('z', 'a'), ('z', 'y'), ('z', 'b')]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your example, definition and question, any edge that connects two nodes that are already connected indirectly will cause a cyclic node.

Therefore if you keep track of which nodes are connected then you can determine if an edge connects a new node or not. If it does not connect a new node then the edge is connected to a cyclic node (maybe saying that it is a cyclic edge is more useful a term in this case?)

edit: I have assumed here that the graph is [undirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956467/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directed-and-undirected-graph), as there is no mention of the edges being directed. If the question is meant to be for a directed graph then my answer is invalid, as you simply can't calculate the loops using sets in a directed graph.

Here is the function:

```
def markcyclicnodes(edges):
    groups = []
    result = []
    for edge in edges:
        cyclicnode = False
        newlink = False
        newnode = False

        group1count = 0
        group2count = 0
        tolink = 0
        todelete = 0
        for group1 in groups:
            if cyclicnode == False and newlink == False and newnode == False:
                if edge[0] in group1 and edge[1] in group1:
                    cyclicnode = True

                elif edge[0] in group1:
                    tolink = group1count
                    for  group2 in groups:
                        if edge[1] in group2:
                            newlink = True
                            todelete = group2count
                        group2count += 1
                    if newlink == False:
                        groups[group1count].append(edge[1])
                        newnode = True

                elif edge[1] in group1:
                    tolink = group1count
                    for group2 in groups:
                        if edge[0] in group2:
                            newlink = True
                            todelete = group2count
                        group2count += 1
                    if newlink == False:
                        groups[group1count].append( edge[0])
                        newnode = True
            group1count += 1

        if newlink == False and cyclicnode == False and newnode == False :
            groups.append([edge[0],edge[1]])
        if newlink == True:
            for node in groups[todelete]:
                groups[tolink].append (node)
            del groups[todelete]

        if cyclicnode == True:
            result.append ((edge[0], edge[1]+'@'))
        else:
            result.append(edge)      
    return result
```

Here is my test data:

```
edges1 = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('f', 'e')]
edges2 =  [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'z'), ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'c'), ('z', 'a'), ('z', 'y'), ('z', 'b')]
edges3 = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'),('z', 'bye'), ('bye', 'c'), ('hi', 'shy'),('shy','a'),('shy','z')]
```

here are the results for each set of test data

```
[('a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('d', 'a@'),
 ('a', 'e'),
 ('e', 'a@'),
 ('f', 'e')]
```

```
[('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'z'),
 ('b', 'z@'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('d', 'a@'),
 ('d', 'z@'),
 ('z', 'd@'),
 ('z', 'c@'),
 ('z', 'a@'),
 ('z', 'y'),
 ('z', 'b@')]
```

```
[('a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('z', 'bye'),
 ('bye', 'c'),
 ('hi', 'shy'),
 ('shy', 'a'),
 ('shy', 'z@')]
```

Comment: If the test data was `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z')]`, I think you would mark 'z@' as *reached again*, while there is no cycle.

Comment: there is a cycle, a->b b->z z->a. I stand by my comment that if you connect anything to the set that is already in the set then you create a cycle

Comment: Please edit into your answer whether to consider *directed* or *undirected graphs* - I wish the question was explicit about this.

Answer (score 0):

the short variant:

```
a = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('f', 'e')]

repeated_nodes = set()
result = []

for edge in a:
    if edge[1] not in repeated_nodes:
        result.append(edge)
    else:
        result.append((edge[0], f'@{edge[1]}'))
    repeated_nodes.add(edge[0])

print(result)

[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', '@a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', '@a'), ('f', '@e')]
```

or if you like comprehensions then:

```
repeated_nodes = set()
result = []

for edge in a:
    result.append(edge if edge[1] not in repeated_nodes else (edge[0], f'@{edge[1]}'))
    repeated_nodes.add(edge[0])

print(result)

[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', '@a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', '@a'), ('f', '@e')]
```